# Autodesk Forge/BIM 360 update releases

Tags: autodesk-forge

There must be a place where the new update releases are identified?
Unfortunately we are not aware of where to find this information
The Autodesk Health dashboard just tells you how things are working and maintenance

Talking with Cyrille apparently there was a update released for BIM 360 last week that might be the cause of our latest issue

Any direction on this would help us when we have an issue and give us more insight where to look for resolution

Comment: Hi David, which BIM 360 API did you see breaking?  Could it be that svf2 and properties API?  
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/svf2-ga-new-streaming-web-format-forge-viewer-moving-production
(We also temporarily suspended spooler as an emergency update with DA for Revit due to security vulnerability identified. 
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-revit-disable-xps-printing )
If it is anything else, we need to know.  
For any changes that might affect developers, we try to communicate in advance through blog and newsletter. But we are aware that we need to do better.

Comment: It appears to be the properties as they are not lining up to the elements that are converted. I spoke with Cyrille and he is working on a fix for the BIM360 release last week and he feels it is related to our issues with model conversions

So where is the best place to get notification of changes or can we submit an email to get notified of upcoming changes so we can test before release?